# Trocar de Senha no primeiro acesso usando Identity Asp Net Erro ao mandar Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp, identity

Estou com um problema para implementação de uma funcionalidade.
A ideia é: *Fazer que o Usuário troque de senha ao primeiro acesso*(Já que o usuário é criado por outra pessoa).

Como estou usando o `Identity`, peguei lógica do método **ForgotPassword** e coloquei dentro do Método **Register** (Ambos do `Controller Account`), assim quando o administrador criar um novo usuário, já é mandado um e-mail para o usuário com o link para "trocar a senha", assim ele já troca de senha e entra no Sistema. O Problema que quando ele vai mandar o *e-mail* ele da o seguinte erro no método que manda e-mail:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'O servidor SMTP requer uma conexão segura ou o cliente não foi autenticado.

No método que manda e-mail do Identity (**public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)** )

**Esse é o Método que dá o Erro:**

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    // cria uma mensagem
    MailMessage mensagemEmail = new MailMessage("test289email@gmail.com", message.Destination, "Confirmação de Cadastro", message.Body);

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("test289email@gmail.com", "senha123");
    client.Credentials = cred;

    // inclui as credenciais
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    // envia a mensagem
    client.Send(mensagemEmail);

    // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Alguém que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Só uma dúvida, esta conta de e-mail `test289email@gmail.com` existe no gmail?

Comment: Existe sim JcSaint

Comment: Deu certo!!
Muito Obrigado Barletta!